# Hang on websocket.recv() after... something?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

Apologies for the ambiguous question - I actually have no idea what I changed that stopped this from working.

I'm working on a text adventure engine (open source project) in Python using Websockets. <s>This was working fine with the asyncio and websockets modules. I moved things around a bit and now it hangs upon receiving input.</s>

I lied - it never worked. This code however, does work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import asyncio
import websockets
import time

async def hello(websocket, path):
    while True:
        name = await websocket.recv()
        print("< {}".format(name))

        greeting = ''.join(name + "... " for x in range(5))
        await websocket.send(greeting)
        print("> {}".format(greeting))

        time.sleep(0.1);

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, '', 26231)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

My code (the code that doesn't work) is available on the respective GitHub repo:

https://github.com/KernelDeimos/mmota-server/issues/1

Later when I have the time I'll add a repository for my client and link that here as well, though it's very basic (no changes were made to the client between the working commit and the broken one).

The client connects to localhost:26231 and sends a message that I type (ex: "echo")

The server sends back the message - or at least, it's supposed to.

Unfortunately, the server hangs on this line of server.py:

```
data = await self.websocket.recv()
```

and the print on the next line is never executed.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info): http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/323276

Comment: I deleted my post on Programmers StackExchange. Would you be so kind as to revert the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not determined to use the websockets package, I would suggest trying [Autobahn Python](http://autobahn.ws/python/websocket/programming.html#). I believe it would be easier to use if you're just starting out with websockets.

There's a full echo server example located [here](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/asyncio/websocket/echo).

Comment: I've went and implemented Autobahn - it looks promising so far! I haven't yet reached the point where I want to split off into two coroutines (like in my code on the commit I referred to), but I think it'll be much easier with this way